# Is there a way to modify the search script to allow either lowercase or uppercase?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have added the code below that I'm currently working on. I am trying to enable the search to allow the search text to be either Uppercase or Lowercase. Currently it only renders search results when the entire word is typed as shown: "Turnips"

`

```
//SEARCH FOR MATCHED CONTENTS ;
function search(searchtext){
  var spreadsheetId  23456 = '1'; //** CHANGE !!!!
  var sheetName = "A-Z"
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName).getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var ar = [];
```

`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Search ignore case:

```
function search(searchtext){
  var sheetName = "A-Z"
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheetId").getSheetByName(sheetName).getDataRange();
  var data = range.createTextFinder(searchtext).matchCase(false).findall();
```

- [Class textFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)